# Using Xcode 4, can I get rid of a git repository but keep my whole project in its current state?

Tags: xcode, git

I started using a git repository in Xcode 4 without previously knowing git and it looks like I've messed up the state of the repository. I first made a repository, made many commits on it, then made a branch and made many commits on the branch. Then I tried to merge the branch back to the master branch using the Xcode organizer but it won't let me switch to the master branch. When I try to switch to the master branch I get the error: "you need to resolve your current index first". I don't know what that means exactly. I did a commit and everything is up-to-date. I don't see anything in Xcode menus or screens that mentions "index". After reading some postings about git and playing with the git command line I'm clearly lost and have no clue what to do.

I know the right thing to do is learn git and learn how to use the command line tool, but I don't want to take the time for that now. I don't really need the repository functions anyway, I was only using them to see what they were like. I could keep copies of the whole directory and/or I could use snapshots to give me a way to go back to an earlier state.

The current state of the code on the branch I've been working on is fine, so what I'd like to do it un-git it. IOW eliminate the repository altogether but keep the project in its current state. Is there a way to do that? I don't need to go back to the project state on the master branch, I only need the current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick way to un-git a project is open Terminal, go to the project directory, and remove the .git directory

```
cd ~/Documents/MyProject/
rm -rf .git
```

Be careful with the rm command, you only want to nuke the .git directory.  Not your code.

I don't know how to make the .git directory visible in finder.

Comment: If you want to see invisible files use 'ls -la'

Answer (score 1):

To remove all traces of git delete the .git folder in your main project folder. Also look for any .git* files (eg. .gitignore, .gitmodules). If you have submodules you will need to check your subfolders for these files and the .git directory as well.

On linux, this will do it:

```
find /base/dir -name '.git*' -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick answer. I'm on a Mac. rm -fg .git was fine for my situation.